# Can this query be optimised with indexes, or should I change my schema?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

I have a MySQL table that stores each time a user has downloaded a photo that they've bought.  I want to be able to retrieve the first time each photo was downloaded:

```
SELECT MIN(downloaded) AS downloaded
     , photoId
     , size
     , transactionId

FROM ORDER_DOWNLOADS

GROUP BY photoId, size, transactionId
```

I've got an index on `photoId, size, transactionId, downloaded`, as well as single-column indexes on each column.

With 50,000 rows this takes around a second.

Can I simply improve it substantially with a rewrite or a better index, or is my best bet to add a "firstDownload" bit column that I set to 1 upon an initial download and 0 on any subsequent downloads of the same photo/size/transaction?

Thanks!

explain:

- id **1**
- select type **SIMPLE**
- table **ORDER_DOWNLOADS**
- partitons **null**
- type **index**
- possible **keys photoId, size, transactionId, downloaded, covering**
- key **covering**
- key_len **87**
- ref **null**
- rows **43878** (I was being approximate when I said 50,000 earlier, this is the whole table)
- filtered **100**
- Extra **Using index**

Comment: Did you do an explain of the SQL to see how the result is fetched? Did it do a full table scan or did it use the indexes?

Comment: It uses the index but returns all 50,000 rows, I presume because of the `MIN` aggregate?

Comment: Added explain to original question.

Comment: Provide us with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ORDER_DOWNLOADS\G` - although 1s for 50k records doesn't appear too shoddy!

Comment: Sounds like a "cold" cache.  Run it twice.  How many rows in the resultset?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this request is fully optimized on a SQL point of view. Meanwhile, you may can increase performance by choosing a particular type of index depending on your data (for example BINARY for IDs), check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) documentation for more details.

Moreover you have to keep in mind that the innoDB engine in MySQL (if you're using it) may be slow on a big amout of data.

Comment: I am using innoDB, but I don't think we can call < 50,000 rows a big amount of data can we?